# Caching results seemingly slower than recomputing results

Tags: python

I have a function that checks if there is a time conflict between two events.

Each event_combination looks like this: [['5802', '6780', '5803'], ['5788', '6281'], ['6289'], ['5793'], ['6289']] where each number represents a unique id of an event.

I check if there is a conflict between each pair of events (5802, 6780), (5802, 5803), (5802, 5788) etc and as soon as one pair has a conflict, the rest of the pairs are skipped and we move onto the next event_combination.

To make the program more efficient, I tried storing the tuple of conflicting events in a set and checking if it is a known conflict before calling the IsConflict function. However when running the code, it seems caching and checking the result first is slower than calling the function each time.

Is there a reason caching the result is not improving the efficiency of the program?

```
conflicts = set()
valid_combinations = []

def IsConflict(event1, event2):
        s1, e1 = int(times[event1]['beginTime']), int(times[event1]['endTime'])
        s2, e2 = int(times[event2]['beginTime']), int(times[event2]['endTime'])
        if (s1 < e2) and (e1 > s2):
            conflicts.add((event1, event2))
            return True
    return False

start = time.perf_counter()

for event_combination in data:
    conflict = False        
    for pair in combinations([event_id for sub_ary in event_combination for event_id in sub_ary], 2):
        if (pair[0], pair[1]) in conflicts:
            conflict = True
            break
        elif IsConflict(*pair):
            conflict = True
            break
    if not conflict:
        valid_combinations.append(event_combination)
        
print(time.perf_counter()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check how often the set short circuits the condition.  If you don't have a high percentage of conflicts, checking the set only adds overhead.

An alternate way to optimize this would be to extract the start/end times only once and use the tuples for combinations.  This will avoid repeatedly using double indirections to get to these times:

```
for event_combination in data:
    conflict = False
    timeRanges = ( (int(times[event_id]['beginTime']), int(times[event_id]['endTime'])) 
                   for sub_ary in event_combination for event_id in sub_ary )       
    for (s1,e1),(s2,e2) in combinations(timeRanges, 2):
        if (s1 < e2) and (e1 > s2):
            conflict = True
            break
    if not conflict:
        valid_combinations.append(event_combination)
```

If the events are in chronological order of their beginTime or endTime, further optimisation would be possible using a binary search. This would give a time complexity of O(NlogN) instead of the O(N^2) of the combinations approach.

Comment: The list "data" contains ~330, 000 event_combinations. The if statement that checks if the tuple of two events is in the conflicts set already runs ~275, 000 times (the function call is bypassed). And the number of conflict tuples at the end of the program is 150.

Comment: How large are the `event_combination` lists?  If they are small lists and given that you are excluding 90% of them, you should have better performance using the conflicts set.  If they are large lists, then the number of combinations for each of them grows exponentially and exclusions will merely cut half of the square of the size on average.  So the overhead of set checking may still outweigh the benefit.

Comment: For example, if you have 10 events on average, there will be 55 combinations to check for each of them.   So, for 90% of the data items, you will check 27 combinations (55/2 on average) to find the conflict.  The set check will return False 26 times and True one time.  This means that it must be at least 26 times faster than the function just to give equal performance.